# Starting a ASP.net WebApp using IISExpress from the command line

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I'm looking for a means to either programmatically or from the command line  starting and stopping a WebApp project via IISExpress. I've tried using the command line (as outlined [here](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line)) - when i run the following command

```
iisexpress /path:<folder to bin folder of my webapi>
```

IISExpress seemingly starts a webapi instance but it's not the named instance of my webapp (it's 'Development Web Site'). Additionally when i attempt to access it via a url i get a 404 not found error, confirming that it's not the specified webapp that's running. I can start it from VS and see in IISExpress the correct named instance but i need to be able to start it running outside VS (and ideally have some means to stop it also).

Comment: It should point to root folder of your website not bin folder.

Comment: Brilliant - that worked ! Add your comment as the answer and i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using path with IISExpress commandline it should point to root folder of your website not bin folder.

`iisexpress /path:c:\myapp\`